# Does webkit-scrollbar work with webkit-transition?

Tags: webkit

I want a custom webkit-scrollbar to animate a different background color for the hover state. The code below changes the color on hover but doesn't animate anything. It works on a div so I suspect webkit-scrollbar doesn't play nice with transitions.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #a8a8a8;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not implemented.  We should file a bug on http://bugs.webkit.org/

Comment: Thanks. I filed a Radar bug for this.

Comment: @Trev: Is the Radar bug public and/or does it have an equivilant bug on webkit's bugzilla for us to follow?

Comment: Still not implemented. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can still apply your transition by setting your `-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` background-color to `inherit` and apply transition to parent element - in this case the scrollbar container itself.

The only drawback is that, you have to create an inner container that would mask it's parent color and set scrollbar track background to the same masking color. Here it is an example:

**Set container colors and transition**

```
.container {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container:hover {
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
}

.container .inner {
  background-color: #FFFFFF; 
}
```

**Set scrolbar colors**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: inherit;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly easy to achieve using xb1itz's `background-color: inherit;` technique in addition with `-webkit-background-clip: text;`.

Live demo; https://jsfiddle.net/s10f04du/

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
  .container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    transition: background-color .8s;
  }
  .container:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.18);  
  }
  .container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: inherit;
  }
}
```

Comment: This causes ghosting if you scroll, at least in Chrome 68.0.3440.106.